# Visualising Cauchy's root test

Tags: sequences-and-series

[1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gfqckWCX_6UVLyloYF3kywpyVTZpv8dO/view?usp=drivesdk)

[2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1or4Lb7_YGpzLNJ-FB4pmqU5rDcI1Y740/view?usp=drivesdk)

There are two statements of Cauchy's root test ( I think they are equivalent but don't know why ).

In [1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gfqckWCX_6UVLyloYF3kywpyVTZpv8dO/view?usp=drivesdk) ,
  $ \sum u_n $ be a  series
 converges if $ \lim_{n \to \infty}  { (u_n)^{1/n}} \lt 1$

and diverges if $ \lim_{n \to \infty}  { (u_n)^{1/n} } \gt 1$.

And the test fails if $ \lim_{n \to \infty}  { (u_n)^{1/n}} = 1$ .

In [2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1or4Lb7_YGpzLNJ-FB4pmqU5rDcI1Y740/view?usp=drivesdk) , 
$ \sum u_n $ be a  series
 converges if $ \limsup { (u_n)^{1/n}} \lt 1$

and diverges if $ \limsup { (u_n)^{1/n} } \gt 1$.

And the test fails if $ \limsup { (u_n)^{1/n}} = 1$ .

I have no idea why they are equivalent.
I know that $ \limsup $ of a sequence is the highest value to which the subsequences of the sequence converge.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

They are NOT equivalent. $\lim\sup$ always exists but this is obviously false for $\lim$.

Comment: So which one is correct ??

Comment: @PNDas, **both** are correct, but (1) is a *particular* case of (2).

Comment: Can you please explain your answer and how lim and lim superior related

Comment: @PNDas, **if** $\lim$ exists then $\lim = \lim\sup$.